# Rails Form Processing: how to process radio buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have a standard controller `users`, generated by scaffolding and motified a little bit. Using migration, I changed `:gender` and `:orientation` field types from integer to string.
I have a view with a form to submit new entries to the users table:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<%= f.label :first_Name %><br><%= f.text_field :first_name %><br>
<%= f.label :last_name %><br><%= f.text_field :last_name %><br>
<%= f.radio_button :orientation, false %><%= f.label :orientation, "Straight" %>
<%= f.radio_button :orientation, false %><%= f.label :orientation, "Gay" %>
<%= f.radio_button :orientation, false %><%= f.label :orientation, "Bi" %><br>
<%= f.submit "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

However when I check the database itself, `:gender` and `:orientation` are both 'false'. I would like them to be the values chosen by the user.

How can I do this? What is wrong here?

Also, would it be better to have boolean fields for each choice?

```
:man :boolean
:woman :boolean
:gay :boolean
```

etc.

Comment: I would recommend creating a separate `orientations` table and `genders` table. Then have an `orientation_id` and `gender_id` on `users`.

Comment: Thanks. This has been discussed [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786435/rails-database-design-use-strings-or-integer). Basically there are varying opinios as to how much you should normalize the database. And considering the fact I'm not making the next Facebook, I think I can live with a little bit of redudent data. I am already planning to add a dozen or so tables for normalizing other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code:

```
I am:<br>
<%= f.radio_button :gender, "Male" %><%= f.label :gender, "Man" %>
<%= f.radio_button :gender, "Female" %><%= f.label :gender, "Woman" %><br>

Sexsual Orientation:<br>
<%= f.radio_button :orientation, "Straight" %><%= f.label :orientation, "Straight" %>
<%= f.radio_button :orientation, "Gay" %><%= f.label :orientation, "Gay" %>
<%= f.radio_button :orientation, "Bi" %><%= f.label :orientation, "Bi" %
```

Comment: Sexsual? Is the misspelling intentional?

Answer (score 0):

try check_box instead of radio_button?

```
<%= f.check_box :man %>
```

Comment: I don't know if that would work, since technically someone can't be both a man and a woman. Users would have to choose between the two.